# Reverse Iterator not working as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using a reverse iterator on a `std::vector` and according to the following link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/rbegin/

`myVector.rbegin()` is the last element of the vector. In my case, I am actually getting the `past the end` iterator on `rbegin()` and the fist element from `rend()`. I would have expected `rend()` to give me `past the end` iterator and `rbegin()` to give me the last element in the container. Did I understand the whole thing wrong?

The following is my code, nothing special. I put a break point just after the assignments, and the above is the result I am getting in the debugger (`VecDebugCubes` is a type define for a `std::vector<myStructure>`)

```
VecDebugCubes::reverse_iterator itr    = pActiveDebugCubes.rbegin();
VecDebugCubes::reverse_iterator itrEnd = pActiveDebugCubes.rend();
while (itr != itrEnd)
{
  (*itr)->printDebugValues();
  ++itr;
}
```

Comment: Could you post here more complete code snippet? Something like from the link you provided.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit with more code, although, it is almost exactly like the example

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/base/.

Dereferencing a reverse iterator will return a different value than the one that you see it pointing to in your debugger.

Comment: The problem is, I had to debug is because it was crashing. The dereferenced reverse iterator, `*itr`, was null and `itr + 1` was the element that I was expecting in `itr`

Answer (score 0):

past the end for rbegin() and the first element for rend() is how the iterator is supposed to work. That's why it's called a reverse iterator. It's designed such that you can use it in a for loop without having to bother about making a mistake about the start and end points of the range. You'll notice that a simple i++ can be used for the iterator, and the iterator actually iterates backward on the range.
I guess all you need to know is, that that's how it is supposed to work. There's nothing wrong. It just makes your life easier since you're less likely to make a mistake while writing **for(i=beginAtTheEnd to finishAtTheStart and decrement-i-in-the-same-way-as-i++)** rather than having **for(i=10;i>0;i--)**, where you might make the mistake of putting **i<0** or **i>1** in the condition. This is a simplified example. You'll appreciate it more when you want to reverse iterate on a container.